# Access crashes at shutdown

Tags: vba, ms-access, crash

We maintain ~130 VBA-Applications which are running in Access. But one of them crashes Access when its closed.

But only if either the VBE (The VBA-development-enviroment built into Access) is opened or the VBA-Code is accessed directly via automation (e.g. like this: [Extract VBA-Code from Access via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50816715/extract-vba-code-from-access-via-c-sharp) )

Any ideas where the problem might be or any tipps how to find the reason for the crash?

Comment: If you don't have a clue why it crashes, I guess it's because the code is run on Open event. In this case, 1) Turn off Macros on your office. 2) Open the VBA code of the project crashing and put some strategic breakpoints 3) Re-enable macros 4) Get into the point crashing to have more tips.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to diagnose MS access crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279330/how-to-diagnose-ms-access-crashes)

Comment: @Matteo NNZ: Ok, Ill try your suggestions

Comment: @Erik von Asmuth: Thank you. Ill check the other question too

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon: Yes I do run rubberduck. Ill check if my coworkers (they dont use Rubberduck) have the same problem.

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: It's also possible that you're *replicating* an issue that we closed in Rubberduck if you're running something similar to the [linked code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50816715/4088852). Access is kind of touchy about having its document modules read from managed code via Interop. I'm pretty sure we have it documented on [this issue](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/3614).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier version of [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) (prior to v2.2) are known to have teardown issues that caused the host application to crash with an *access violation*.

See if <s>uninstalling Rubberduck</s> updating Rubberduck to the [latest version](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/releases/latest) (we released v2.3 yesterday), fixes it.

As for a reason - Rubberduck is running in-process as a managed (.NET) library, constantly interoperating with the VBE's unmanaged/COM objects; until v2.2 we were running into issues with COM interop in .NET. These issues are resolved now.

Comment: ok, it seems to have worked. I didnt know that rubberduck is loaded when I just use the automation via interopt...